# Why does the Firepad CodeMirror example not have any color-coded syntax on my Project?

Tags: firebase

I created a new Visual Studio project and tried running the Code Editing (CodeMirror) example shown at this link: https://firepad.io/examples/ . It runs fine, however I don't have any of the nice color-coded syntax as it does on the firepad example.

To clarify, in the example, the word "function" should be highlighted purple, however on my project all the text is simply black. It is as if I am using Notepad rather than a code editor. Any ideas why this would be the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing this script:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.17.0/mode/javascript/javascript.js